# Can I install Ubuntu without installation media?

Tags: 12.10, hard-drive, drive

I was curious what the best way to install Ubuntu would be in my current situation. I have second HDD, completely clean. I want to install Ubuntu but I don't have a disk to burn to or a USB flash drive to put it on. Any ideas or thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - this will show you how to do just that: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This didn't really help. I have a second hard drive in the same computer. I need to install it onto that hard drive while I am booted into windows.

Comment: @Kody, in this case have a look at this article - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromWindows.